# Return rows from a table and add field for that row if the ID has a relationship with another table

Tags: sql, amazon-aurora

DBMS used: Amazon Aurora

I have a table that I store a list of all my products, let's call it `products`

```
+----+--------------+
| id | product_name |
+----+--------------+
| 1  | Product 1    |
+----+--------------+
| 2  | Product 2    |
+----+--------------+
|    |              |
+----+--------------+
```

Another table called `redeemed_products` stores the ID of the product that the user has redeemed.

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | user_id | product_id |
+----+---------+------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1          |
+----+---------+------------+
|    |         |            |
+----+---------+------------+
|    |         |            |
+----+---------+------------+
```

I would like to retrieve all rows of `products` and add an extra field to the row which has a relation in the `redeemed_products`

```
+----+--------------+----------+
| id | product_name | redeemed |
+----+--------------+----------+
| 1  | Product 1    | true     |
+----+--------------+----------+
| 2  | Product 2    |          |
+----+--------------+----------+
|    |              |          |
+----+--------------+----------+
```

The purpose of this is to retrieve the list of products and it will show which of the product has already been redeemed by the user. I do not know how I should approach this problem.

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output. Also mention the DBMS *(Oracle,SQL server,MySQL etc.,)* that you are using.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy Done

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: you just need a left join where `products` table is on the left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an outer join:

```
select p.id, p.product_name, rp.product_id is not null as redeemed
from products p
  left join redeemed_products rp on rp.product_id = p.id;
```

Note that this will repeat rows from the `products` table if the `product_id` occurs more than once in the `redeemed_products` table (e.g. the same `product_id` for multiple `user_id`s).

If that is the case you could use a scalar sub-select:

```
select p.id, p.product_name,
       exists (select * 
               redeemed_products rp 
               where rp.product_id = p.id) as redeemed
from products p;
```

You haven't tagged your DBMS, but the above is standard ANSI SQL, but not all DBMS products actually support boolean expressions like that in the SELECT list.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using a conditional within a LEFT JOIN query :

```
SELECT p.*, CASE WHEN r.product_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' END AS redeemed
  FROM products p
  LEFT JOIN redeemed_products r
    ON r.product_id = p.id
```